# LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_56.lib'

Tags: c++, boost

I get this error when trying to compile in VS2010:

LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_56.lib'

I have read through many similar questions here on stackoverflow but still cant fix it.

The file 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_56.lib' is present but 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_56.lib' (note the s in sgd versus gd) is not in my lib folder.

I probably need to change someting in the project settings to get rid of the s!? 
Or I need to compile the boost libraries in a different way? 
Or it is none of the above..!?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Maybe it helps, I'm trying to compile voronoi.cpp from https://github.com/thegrandpoobah/voronoi

I downloaded Boost 1.56 and compiled the libraries binary using:

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

as described in the getting started file.

Comment: how do you link the boost library from VS ?

Comment: Doesn't s mean static library. So the problem is static versus dynamic libraries.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tutorial/linkage.html

Comment: did you set the path to the location of the boost libraries in you linker path?

Comment: @Piotr S. and Mgetz: I added the path the compiler include path and the link to the stage/lib folder to the linker include path. To see all my settings for the projects please see: http://screencast.com/t/ddTOEt4F2MM

Comment: @MadSienceDreams and drescherjm: the s does indeed indicate static but I havn't got a clue on how to fix this :(

Answer (score 1):

### In Short

You are linking against static libraries (hence the 's' in the lib name). Probably because you are generating your project under the "Multithreaded" or "Multithreaded Debug" setting in "Code Generation" under Visual Studio.

These libraries are not built by default when you build boost with

`b2`

You need to run instead

`b2 build-type=complete`

to also generate static versions of the boost libs.

### In details

In file `boostcpp.jam`, build options are defined (for Windows target) as:

```
self.minimal-properties-win = [ property-set.create <variant>debug
        <variant>release <threading>multi <link>static <runtime-link>shared
        <address-model>32 <address-model>64 ] ;

self.complete-properties = [ property-set.create
    <variant>debug <variant>release
    <threading>multi
    <link>shared <link>static
    <runtime-link>shared <runtime-link>static ] ;

self.complete-properties-win = [ property-set.create
    <variant>debug <variant>release
    <threading>multi
    <link>shared <link>static
    <runtime-link>shared <runtime-link>static
    <address-model>32 <address-model>64 ] ;
```

The `<link>` options stand for the built libs themselves, whereas `<runtime-link>` stand for the type of lib they actually are once built.

So with `minimal-properties`, you do not generate `<runtime-link>static`, which is what you are looking for with the `s` in the name suffix.